# How to migrate primary system drive from RAID array to SSD with Windows already installed?

Tags: windows-10, boot, ssd, raid, migration

I currently have an SSD (C:) with Windows 10 installed on it (C:/Windows/*). I also have a RAID 1+0 array of 4 HDDs (D:) that does not have an OS installed. I would like to remove the RAID (D:) entirely, and only have the SSD (C:). All of my data is on the SSD, I have backed up all of the data on the RAID array.

Disk management shows the RAID disk (D:) as System, Active, Primary Partition. It shows the SSD (C:) as Boot, Page File, Crash Dump, Primary Partition.

[image: Disk Management]

I tried physically removing the RAID disks from the machine and selecting the SSD as the primary boot drive in BIOS, but could not get past a "Reboot and Select Proper Boot Device" message after BIOS. I also tried changing the BIOS boot mode from RAID to UEFI, but then got a "Could not find OS" message after BIOS.

I'm looking for advice on the proper order of operations to:

- Change the System disk from RAID (D:) to SSD (C:)
- Remove the RAID disk in Windows
- Update BIOS boot mode to UEFI

...all without losing/overwriting any data on the SSD (C:).

Comment: Your issue is that you have a single 1.8 TB system partition, when it should be a separate partition, there any particular reason you made a data partition your system partition?

Comment: Not that I can recall. It's been 5 years or so since I created this particular setup.

Comment: Setting `C:` as an active partition with `diskpart` and something like `bcdboot C:\Windows /s C: /f BIOS` should make it work. (Even if it does not, it shouldn't stop you from being able to boot with the RAID volume.)

Comment: There's also a chance that `bootsect /nt60 C: /mbr` is needed additionally, although not very likely.